# How to re-render Ember components with google maps

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ember.js

**First the code:**

I have created an Ember component which renders Google Maps v3 map like:

```
App.GoogleMapsComponent = Ember.Component.extend(
classNames: ['ember-view-map']

insertMap: (->
  @getUserLatLng()
  options =
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(
      @get('latitude'),
      @get('longitude')
    )
    zoom: 14
    draggable: false
    zoomControl: false
    panControl: false
    streetViewControl: false
    scaleControl: false
    mapTypeControl: false
    scrollwheel: false
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

  @set 'map', new google.maps.Map(@$('.map-container')[0], options)
  @set 'markerCache', []
  @coordinatesChanged()
  @setMarkers()
).on('didInsertElement')

getUserLatLng: ->
  self = @
  if !@.get('latitude') || !@.get('longitude')
    $.ajax
      url: '//ipinfo.io/json',
      success: (response) ->
        self.set('latitude', response.loc.split(',')[0])
        self.set('longitude', response.loc.split(',')[1])
      ,
      dataType: 'json'

coordinatesChanged: (->
  map = @get('map')
  if map
    map.setCenter new google.maps.LatLng(@get('latitude'), @get('longitude'))
    map.setZoom map.getZoom()
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
  return
).observes('latitude', 'longitude')
```

Component template is:

```
.map-wrapper
  .map-container
```

And I use it in other outlet like:

```
.row.row-map
 .col-md-12.col-map
   google-maps latitude=location.latitude longitude=location.longitude markers=markers
```

**Issue and scenarios**

1. First scenario

This outlet is routed to my '/' and now if I render this page by entering URL from browser it renders this component just fine.

2. Second scenario

I visit other page in app and use `link-to` link to transition to my '/', google-maps component renders fine.

3. Third scenario (**with issues**)

I visit '/', transition to other page using `link-to` let's say page `about` and from there I get back to '/' also using `link-to` link. Then the component is not rendered properly.

I can see proper DOM elements but google map is not resized to full width/height it shows just one layer of map in left-top corner like:

[image: failure when re-rendering map]

So the issue occurs when I try to re-render the component because when it renders first time it looks fine. I thought that the component is destroyed completely when transitioning to other route and it looks like it when I tried to log this object in console it is undefined after transitioning to route other than '/'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, was looking in wrong place :) 
The issue was in `coordinatesChanged` function, I tried to trigger resize function on Google Maps when `if map` condition was true but as component is destroyed and re-rendered on transition I've to fetch lat/lng again so I was resizing map with `undefined` coordinate. Fixed function looks like:

```
coordinatesChanged: (->
  if @get('map') && @get('latitude') && @get('longitude')
    @get('map').setCenter new google.maps.LatLng(@get('latitude'), @get('longitude'))
    @get('map').setZoom @get('map').getZoom()
    google.maps.event.trigger(@get('map'), 'resize')
  ).observes('latitude', 'longitude')
```

So simply I have to resize when `map` object exists and **both** coordinates are defined.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option, rather than rolling your own, I would suggest using the [Ember Google Map](https://github.com/huafu/ember-google-map) component, since it seems to do what you need. It is available through npm: `npm i ember-google-map`. If that isn't up your alley, then you can dig through the source to see what is needed to properly re-render the map.

Comment: Thanks, for answer Oren, I'm not a big fan of using external add-on/gem for very simple component, what I want is simple map with markers so it would be much easier to maintain when it is written by my own. From what I checked Ember Google Map add-on looks awesome but it is over complication in my case.